# Traer elementos faltantes con LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Partiendo de dos tablas

*lessons*

```
lessons.lessons_id, lessons.lesson_number, lessons.course_id entre otras
```

y *lessons_completed*

```
lessons_completed.lessons_number, lessons_completed.user_id, 
lessons_completed.completed
```

Con el siguiente código, LEFT JOIN funciona de mil maravillas, sin embargo, borre todos los registros de la tabla *lessons_completed* y como era obvio me dejo de mostrar los ejercicios de la tabla *lessons*, y si agrego registros del usuario en la tabla *lessons_completed*  me van apareciendo los ejercicios con su respectivo check, eso está muy bien, pero ya no me muestra los ejercicios que aún no ha completado el usuario.

para mostrar el check sólo utilizo un if a la columna:

```
if $lesson[completed]==1 {
muestro el check 
}  else { 
   NO OK
}
```

En la columna *lessons_completed.completed* sólo hay valores 1 el 0 no existe porque el registro se crea cuando el usuario hace click en *Completada* con un insert

Vuelvo a agregar el código como quedó después de las recomendaciones de ustedes

```
     public function get_lessons_completed($args = array()) {
    global $db;
    $user_id = !isset($args['user_id']) ? null : $args['user_id'];
    $course_id = !isset($args['course_id']) ? null : $args['course_id'];
    $lessons_completed = array();

            $get_lessons_completed = $db->query
            ("SELECT
                 lessons.lesson_id,
                 lessons.course_id,
                 lessons.lesson_number,
                 lessons.lesson_intro,
                 lessons.lesson_text,
                 lessons.lesson_date,
                 lessons.lesson_prev,
                 lessons.lesson_top,
                 LC.lesson_number,
                     LC.completed
                 FROM lessons

                 LEFT JOIN lessons_completed LC

                 ON lessons.lesson_number = LC.lesson_number

               WHERE lessons.course_id = 2 AND LC.user_id= 2 ORDER BY 
            lessons.lesson_number

            ") or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);

          if($get_lessons_completed->num_rows > 0) {
            while($lesson_completed = $get_lessons_completed->fetch_assoc()) {

            $lessons_completed[] = $lesson_completed;
        }
     }
      return $lessons_completed;
     }
```

Hasta aquí todo excelente, Ahora la pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo hacer o que me falta para traer los ejercicios de la tabla *lessons* que aún no ha completado el usuario? sin que se dupliquen los registros con los que el usuario ya completo?

Aquí se muestran los resultados con el código de arriba, pero hay por ejemplo en este ID DE CURSO en la tabla *lessons* otros 6 ejercicios que he intentado traer, pero se me duplican con los que ya completo el usuario si hago cambios a la función

[image: Resultado de la función de arriba]

Intente trayendo los nulos con un:

```
OR NULL
```

y el resultado es que se duplican

Ya intente cambiando a INNER y a RIGTH en mi desesperación pero el resultado es el mismo, me trae los mismos datos de la misma forma que como esta actualmente.

Quiza lo ideal sería agregando otro JOIN pero no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo.

Espero me puedan ayudar amigos.  creo que nunca me había enfrentado a resolver una situación que no puedo resolver por mi  mismo, esos JOIN me traen mareado.

Comment: Intenta con `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Gracias alanfcm ya lo probe como dices, y me muestra lo mismo que con LEFT JOIN, sólo los 2 registros que están en *lessons_completed* y sigue sin mostrar lo que está en *lessons*

Comment: Y a todo esto ¿cuál es la columna que une a ambas tablas, pues es ese el *quid* de la cuestión? ¿O es que intervienen dos columnas en la relación y las tablas no se están llenando correctamente?

Comment: Intentalo asi: `LEFT OUTER JOIN lessons_completed LC ON lessons.lesson_number = LC.lesson_number AND lessons.course_id = 2 AND LC.user_id= 2 ORDER BY lessons.lesson_number`

Comment: es lesson_number en ambas, tambien intente cambiando esos valores y agregue otra columna el *lessons_completed* id_lesson que está en *lessons* pero no estaba en *lessons_completed* respetando el mismo id y tampoco

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero creo que el problema pudiera radicar en tu condición del WHERE haces referencia a una Columna que existe en lesson_completed que es esta LC.user_id= 2 prueba quitando esa condición para ver si te traer los registros completos, porque me quiero imaginar que como para los registros que aun no tiene registro en esa tabla el valor es nullo por eso no te los muestra.

Comment: Funciona bien así como lo pones @alanfcm, pero solo me muestra los números de ejercicios que están en lessons_completed es decir me muestra correctamente los ejercicios que están con check y los que no, pero los que no, no me toma el valor de lessons.lesson_number

Comment: Voy a subir una imagen como respuesta

Comment: Pero si quito esa @M. Gress me va a mostrar los mismo para todos los usuarios

Comment: @alanfcm cual es la diferencia entre `LEFT JOIN` y `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?, disculpa la ignorancia, pero no se en que cambio, si se dice que son casi lo mismo

Comment: Mientras @alanfcm te contesta, voy probando con sólo LEFT JOIN ya con la seguridad de que funciona correctamente asi como esta y comento.

Comment: Listo, ya cambie sin OUTER y funciona bien tambien, tengo entendido que es mejor LEFT JOIN , por rendimiento, pero no estoy seguro, necesitaría medir la respuesta con ambas

Comment: Al parecer no hay diferencia entre `LEFT JOIN` y `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  El truco esta en agregar las condiciones del `WHERE` al `JOIN`.

Comment: Si la verdad me voy a tomar el tiempo de estudiar bien esta parte, porque ya me perdí y sólo cambie la linea que me enviaste @alanfcm y funciona y funciona bien con AMBAS, muchas gracias y un fuerte abrazo.

Comment: Me surge una duda, @alanfcm, se fue el WHERE, y se reemplazó por AND ? ya no hay un Where en la consulta, no se como pero funciona.

Comment: Ya , ya entendi el código, muchas gracias, saludos a todos.

Comment: Publique una respuesta para que quede mas claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucion:

```
    SELECT
             lessons.lesson_id,
             lessons.course_id,
             lessons.lesson_number,
             lessons.lesson_intro,
             lessons.lesson_text,
             lessons.lesson_date,
             lessons.lesson_prev,
             lessons.lesson_top,
             LC.completed
     FROM lessons
             LEFT JOIN lessons_completed LC
                 ON
                 lessons.lesson_number = LC.lesson_number
                 AND lessons.course_id = 2
                 AND LC.user_id= 2 ORDER BY lessons.lesson_number
```

Explicacion:

El `LEFT JOIN` permite traer todos los registros de la tabla izquierda sin importar si hay un match en la tabla derecha.  El problema surge al agregar la clausula `WHERE`.  La consulta sigue trayendo todos los registros de la tabla izquierda, pero luego son filtrados por las condiciones del `WHERE` lo que hace que no todos los registros sean mostrados.

La solucion es mover las condiciones del `WHERE` para que sean parte de el `JOIN`.  En este caso la consulta dice: "Une las dos tablas basado en estas condiciones, pero ademas quiero tambien los registros de la tabla izquierda que no cumplan con las mismas"

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado con la recomendación de @alancfm por alguna razón no me toma el valor de la columna lessons.lesson_number para mostrarlo

Answer (score 0):

Código final a muchos estoy seguro les servirá.

```
    public function get_lessons_completed($args = array()) {
    global $db;
    $user_id = !isset($args['user_id']) ? null : $args['user_id'];
    $course_id = !isset($args['course_id']) ? null : $args['course_id'];
    $lessons_completed = array();

            $get_lessons_completed = $db->query
            ("SELECT
                 lessons.lesson_id,
                 lessons.course_id,
                 lessons.lesson_number,
                 lessons.lesson_intro,
                 lessons.lesson_text,
                 lessons.lesson_date,
                 lessons.lesson_prev,
                 lessons.lesson_top,
                     LC.completed
                 FROM lessons

                 LEFT OUTER JOIN lessons_completed LC
                     ON
                     lessons.lesson_number = LC.lesson_number
                     AND lessons.course_id = 2
                     AND LC.user_id= 2 ORDER BY lessons.lesson_number

            ") or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);

    if($get_lessons_completed->num_rows > 0) {
        while($lesson_completed = $get_lessons_completed->fetch_assoc()) {

            $lessons_completed[] = $lesson_completed;
        }
    }
    return $lessons_completed;
    }
```

gracias a @alancfm y a  @M. Gress

Este es el resultado final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya muestra correctamente todos los registros de *lessons* sin que se duplique y respeta el valor de *lessons_completed.completed*